# TwitterAPI: how to streaming multiple users by id

Tags: python, twitter

I'm streaming all tweets that mention one of the usernames (screen_name) that I have on a list( TRACK_TERM ).

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

TRACK_TERM = ['@CNN', '@FoxNews', '@FOXTV', '@BBC'... + 500]
r = api.request('statuses/filter', {'track': TRACK_TERM})
```

My problem is that users might sometimes change their screen_name. So I was wondering if there's a way to track user' mentions by their user `id` instead of their `screen_name`. As this script will run continuously for a month.

I'm using the [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) I also try [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `track` parameter try using the `follow` parameter.

```
USER_IDS = '%d,%d,%d' % (ID1,ID2,ID3)
r = api.request('statuses/filter', {'follow': USER_IDS})
```

The docs are [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter).

Comment: hi @Jonas thanks! 'Follow' is more for the user activity. i.e. what the user @ johndoe tweets and who retweet the user @ johndoe. But 'follow' doesn't retrieve tweets mentioning the user i.e 'What's up @ johndoe'  docs:  https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#follow I will give you an up arrow.

Comment: Hi @PapoucheGuinslyzinho - Sorry for misreading your question, but mentions will not track by id. You are stuck with using the screen name. I guess you could periodically check if the screen has changed with a REST API call.